# How to Create and deploy SSO applications in BizTalk 2020

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, devops, biztalk

We are migrating our application from BizTalk 2013 R2 to BizTalk 2020.In 2013 R2 we used BTDF for deployments that use to take care of adding and deploying the SSO applications. There are some variable that we are reading from sso inside orchestration and now we need to migrate this to 2020. In Biztalk 2020 we are using BizTalk application project with VSTS for automatic deployments. I am struggling to find a good post to add and deploy SSO applications in BizTalk 2020. All I want is to add a SSO application, deploy it in different environments and read variable inside orchestration.

Comment: Could you use a component of BTDF, SSO Settings Importer (SSOSettingsFileImport.exe)  http://www.tfabraham.com/BTDFDocs/V5_0/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkDocs.html?SSOSettingsImporterSSOSettingsFi.html   Or even use BTDF itself in your DevOps pipeline?

Comment: There is a BizTalk 2020 / VS 2019 version of BTDF : https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2021/07/16/biztalk-deployment-framework-btdf-visual-studio-plugin-for-biztalk-server-2020/